# What's a good time to see autumn colors in the Maritime and Cottian Alps?

Tags: alps, autumn

What is a good time of year to see autumn colours in the higher areas of the [Maritime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maritime_Alps) and [Cottian Alps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cottian_Alps), in particular yellow larches such as in [this photo](http://www.panoram-art.com/galerie/france/9364-france-Hautes-Alpes-Vallee-de-la-Claree-Nevache-Massif-des-Cerces-panorama-sentucq.h.jpg)¹?  I may have the opportunity to visit either 27 September – October 1, or October 7–11. Would I have a good chance to see autumn colours during either of these periods?

---

¹<sup>Photo is taken further north than where I intend to go but illustrates the kind of colours I would like to see.</sup>

Comment: I clicked on your link and was told Forbidden, you do not have permission to access.

Comment: Hmm, it gives me 403 now too, it worked earlier.  I will search for another photo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I walked through this area on the [Grande Traversata delle Alpi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grande_Traversata_delle_Alpi) a couple of years back and in some valleys the trees were just beginning to turn by the start of October. I would imagine that this would vary a lot by altitude, by the orientation of the valley, and from year to year.

Note that if you're going into the higher areas in October you should be aware that many of the mountain communities are beginning to shut down for the winter. Huts and shops may have limited opening or be closed, so you need to plan for accommodation and resupply.

[image]

(Autumnal colours on the Pian Ceiol)